# Only primitive types do I need to cast?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use anonymous types in Entity Framework, but I am getting an error about

> Unable to create a constant value

`MinQty` and `MaxQty` are int so I don't know if I need to add to `Convert.ToInt32`?

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

This builds a list object

```
var listOfLicense = (from l in db.License
    select new
    {
        l.ProductId,
        l.MinLicense,
        l.MaxLicense
    }).tolist();
```

This is the larger EF object where I am getting the error am I missing a casting?

```
var ShoppingCart = (from sc in db.ShoppingCarts
Select new model.Shoppingchart{
   ShoppingCartId= sc.Id,
    MinQty = (int)listOfLicense 
        .Where(mt => (int)mt.ProductId == sc.ProductId)
        .Select(mt => (int)mt.MinLicense)
        .Min(mt => mt.Value),
    MaxQty = (int)listOfLicense 
        .Where(mt => (int)mt.ProductId == p.ProductId)
        .Select(mt =>(int) mt.MaxQty)
        .Max(mt => mt.Value)}.tolist();
```

Comment: `Min` and `Max` are aggregate functions, and you're calling two diffrerent aggregates in the same query, probably mixed with other stuff you aren't showing. You likely need separate DB queries or switch to client side evaluation

Comment: @camilo-terevinto is that the only way? I can't do it with subsections ?

Comment: It depends on what your entire query does, but you didn't post everything. If your query could be used with a `GroupBy` then you can continue with one query, otherwise you need multiple queries/client-side evaluation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This builds a list object
>
> var listOfLicense = (from l in db.License
> select new
> {
> l.ProductId,
> l.MinLicense,
> l.MaxLicense
> })

The above example does not build a list of objects. It builds a query to return objects of that anonymous type.

This builds an in-memory list of objects of that type:

```
var listOfLicense = (from l in db.License
  select new
  {
      l.ProductId,
      l.MinLicense,
      l.MaxLicense
  }).ToList();
```

Using `.ToList()` here will execute the query and return a materialized list of the anonymous types. From there, your code *may* work as expected without the exception. However, this is effectively loading the 3 columns from *all* rows in your database table, which may be a problem as the system matures and rows are added.

The error you are getting isn't a casting issue, it is a translation issue. Because your initial query is still just an EF Query, (`IQueryable`) any further querying against it will need to conform to EF limitations. EF has to be able to translate what your expressions are trying to select back into SQL. In your case, what your real code is trying to do is breaking those rules.

Generally it is better to let EF work with the `IQueryable` rather than materializing an entire list to memory. Though to accomplish that we'd need to either see the real code, or a minimum reproducible example.

This code:

```
MinQty = (int)listOfLicense 
    .Where(mt => (int)mt.ParentProductId == p.ProductId)
    .Select(mt => (int)mt.MinLicense)
    .Min(mt => mt.Value),
```

... does not fit with the above anonymous type as there is no correlation between what `mt.ParentProductId` is in relation to the anonymous type. (`p` seems to be associated with that type, not `mt` so there looks to be a lot of Query code missing from your example.)

Edit: based on your updated example:

```
var ShoppingCart = (from sc in db.ShoppingCarts
Select new model.Shoppingchart{
   ShoppingCartId= sc.Id,
    MinQty = (int)listOfLicense 
        .Where(mt => (int)mt.ProductId == sc.ProductId)
        .Select(mt => (int)mt.MinLicense)
        .Min(mt => mt.Value),
    MaxQty = (int)listOfLicense 
        .Where(mt => (int)mt.ProductId == p.ProductId)
        .Select(mt =>(int) mt.MaxQty)
        .Max(mt => mt.Value)}.ToList();
```

It may be possible to build something like this into a single query expression depending on the relationships between ShoppingCart, Product, and Licence. It almost looks like "Licence" really refers to a "Product" which contains a min and max quantity that you're interested in.

Assuming a structure like:

```
public class Product 
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int MinQuantity { get; set; }
    public int MaxQuantity { get; set; } 
    // ...
}

// Here lies a question on how your shopping cart to product relationship is mapped.  I've laid out a many-to-many relationship using ShoppingCartItems

public class ShoppingCart
{
    [Key]
    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; } = new List<ShoppingCartItem>();
}

public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    [Key, Column(0), ForeignKey("ShoppingCart")]
    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public virtual ShoppingCart ShoppingCart{ get; set; }
    [Key, Column(1), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

With something like this, to get shopping carts with their product min and max quantities:

```
var shoppingCarts = db.ShoppingCarts
    .Select(sc => new model.ShoppingCart
    {
       ShoppingCartId = sc.Id,
       Products = sc.ShoppingCartItems
          .Select(sci => new model.Product
          {
              ProductId = sci.ProductId,
              MinQuantity = sci.MinQuantity,
              MaxQuantity = sci.MaxQuantity
          }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

This would provide a list of Shopping Carts with each containing a list of products with their respective min/max quantities.

If you also wanted a Lowest min quantity and highest max quantity across all products in a cart:

```
var shoppingCarts = db.ShoppingCarts
    .Select(sc => new model.ShoppingCart
    {
       ShoppingCartId = sc.Id,
       Products = sc.ShoppingCartItems
          .Select(sci => new model.Product
          {
              ProductId = sci.ProductId,
              MinQuantity = sci.MinQuantity,
              MaxQuantity = sci.MaxQuantity
          }).ToList(),
       OverallMinQuantity = sc.ShoppingCartItems
           .Min(sci => sci.MinQuantity),
       OverallMaxQuantity = sc.ShoppingCartItems
           .Max(sci => sci.MaxQuantity),

    }).ToList();
```

Though I'm not sure how practical a figure like that might be in relation to a shopping cart structure. In any case, with navigation properties set up for the relationship between your entities, EF should be perfectly capable of building an `IQueryable` query for the data you want to retrieve without resorting to pre-fetching lists. One issue with pre-fetching and re-introducing those lists into further queries is that there will be a maximum # of rows that EF can handle. Like with SQL `IN` clauses, there is a maximum # of items that can be parsed from a set.

In any case it sounds like it's provided you with some ideas to try and get to the figures you want.

Comment: I update the post with some extra code is can I use IQueryable?

Comment: I've expanded on the answer a bit based on your updated code, but it sounds like you've made headway in what you were looking to accomplish.